# Set values for CosmosDBTrigger in azure function via parameters in local.settings.json

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that has a CosmosDB trigger. When I have code like this:

```
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "%DATABASENAME%",
        collectionName: "%COLLECTIONNAME%",
        StartFromTime = "2021-08-01T00:00:00Z",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING",
        LeaseCollectionName = "%LEASE_COLLECTIONNAME%",
 CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
      IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
        ILogger log)
```

The function executes with no issues. However, I want to be able to pass the StartFromTime as a parameter as well. When I do something like this (I have the values in the config):

```
   public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "%DATABASENAME%",
        collectionName: "%COLLECTIONNAME%",
        StartFromTime = "%START_FROM_TIME%",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING",
        LeaseCollectionName = "%LEASE_COLLECTIONNAME%",
 CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
      IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
        ILogger log)
```

It looks like the the config values are not taken and it complains that the date is not in the correct format. Has anyone faced this before and how did you solve it?
Similar problem might exist for the StartFromBeginnning since it is a boolean value I assume.

Comment: you are using isolated function or in process function here?

Comment: It is a inprocess .net 6

Comment: You need to hardcode `StartFromTime` value in the definition, though in the package file `StartFromTime` is declared as `string` but internally its getting converted to DateTime [refer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/3559). We can't parse its value neither in local.setting file nor declaring in `CosmosDBTrigger`. 

Coming to `StartFromBeginnning`, while taking `StartFromBeginnning = "%START_FROM_BEGINNING%"`, it will through type error(can't take bool as string) considering its a bool value